# How do I check if my list box already contains the same entry before adding the same new one?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have tried to make a simple C# Windows Forms Application .NET Framework, where I have a class(string Name, string LastName, string Classroom, string DateDay) with three textbox entries and one date time picker entry. All of these entries get saved into a list and a list box. I need to add onto my if statement to check with for each, if the entry I am trying to put into the list/list box is already in the list box. If the entry is duplicate it will give a message box error, if it is not duplicate it will add it using the continuation of the if statement.

Here's my attempt at the duplication check:

```
private void btnAdding_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtName.Text != "" && txtLastName.Text != "" && txtClassroom.Text != "" )
    {
        if (ListBox.Items.Cast<string>().Contains(ListBox.Items.ToString()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This entry already exists.", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else { 
        List.Add(new Student(txtName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtClassroom.Text, dateDay.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")));
        RefreshCheck();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You didnt fill out all the text boxes.", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

public void RefreshCheck()
        {
            ListBox.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < seznam.Count(); i++)
            {
                ListBox.Items.Add(List[i].StudentAdd());
                this.txtName.Clear();
                this.txtLastName.Clear();
                this.txtClassroom.Clear();
                this.dateDay.Value = DateTime.Today;
                this.tabStudent.SelectedTab = this.tabCheck;
            }
        }
```

Here's my original code without the duplication check (just the if statement):

```
private void btnAdding_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtName.Text != "" && txtLastName.Text != "" && txtClassroom.Text != "" )
    {
        List.Add(new Student(txtName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtClassroom.Text, dateDay.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")));
        RefreshCheck();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You didnt fill out all the text boxes.", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

public void RefreshCheck()
        {
            ListBox.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < List.Count(); i++)
            {
                ListBox.Items.Add(List[i].StudentAdd());
                this.txtName.Clear();
                this.txtLastName.Clear();
                this.txtClassroom.Clear();
                this.dateDay.Value = DateTime.Today;
                this.tabStudent.SelectedTab = this.tabCheck;
            }
        }
```

I don't know how to setup the for each loop to check the list box / list entries. Please do help if you know how.

Here is the code on how I add into the list box:

```
List.Add(new Student(txtName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtClassroom.Text, dateDay.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")));
```

Here is the way the class returns the value that gets added into the list box:

```
public string StudentAdd()
    {
        return $"{this.Name} {this.LastName} | {this.Clasroom} | {this.DateOfLeave}";
    }
```

Edited: changed OsveziPregledDijaka() -> RefreshCheck, added RefreshCheck function to code.

Comment: How do you fill the listbox initially? Could you please show the code that add items to the listbox?

Comment: `.Contains(ListBox.Items.ToString())` This isn't doing what you think it's doing.  You presumably have a `Student` items in your list.  You need to check the values of those Student properties for equality.

Comment: @LarsTech I added the code, and yes I kind of thought the contains wont work, I thought id give it a try. But I don't know how to check the actual name, last name, classroom and date in the listbox to the current ones im trying to add.

Comment: What is doing that StudentAdd method?

Comment: I added it right now. :)

Comment: It basically returns the class values to the list box and they get added to the list box.

Comment: Not to distract from your issue, but you are making this hard with your code example.  You've comingled `ListBox`, `List`, `boxPregled`, `seznam`, etc..  It makes it harder to interpret.

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm from slovenia, so I try to adjust the code into English, and to make it more understanding as to what is being used, and the ListBox is the ListBox used in design and the List is a list I created.

Comment: I think it should be all connected now, but if there's anything I missed please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to search into the strings displayed by the listbox. But the code above uses ListBox.Items.ToString() and this will be just the ListBox class name not the individual strings displayed by the ListBox.

So, assuming that your listbox shows the info about the studend using firstname, lastname and classroom, you need to build a string like the one displayed by the items collection

```
 string searchFor = $"{txtName.Text} {txtLastName.Text} {txtClassRoom.Text}";
```

and with that string search the items collection (no need to call Cast())

```
 if (boxListBox.Items.Contains(searchFor))
    ....
 else
    ....
```

Here the complete event click handler rewritten

```
private void btnAdding_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtName.Text != "" && txtLastName.Text != "" && txtClassroom.Text != "" )
    {
        string searchFor = $"{txtName.Text} {txtLastName.Text} {txtClassRoom.Text}";
        if (boxListBox.Items.Contains(searchFor))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This entry already exists.", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else 
        { 
            List.Add(new Student(txtName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtClassroom.Text, dateDay.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")));
            RefreshCheck();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You didnt fill out all the text boxes.", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I make this string in the main .cs file or the Student class .cs file?

Comment: You create the comparison string in the code where you do your search.

Comment: Notice  that you should search the items in the currenct instance of the listbox. It seems that you call it _boxListBox_

Comment: Do you maybe have discord or anything of the sorts where I could maybe show you my code? and you could help me more literally? Cause i'm just completely lost here.

Comment: Also looking at that RefreshCheck, you don't need to clear the items and do a loop over the items. Just clear the textbox to be ready for the next input

Comment: aha okay, ill try it out

Comment: I tried it out, and it still adds the duplicated entry into the list box..

Comment: The variable names should be more clear. ListBox is the class name, you should use a more descriptive name for the variable. Also List is confusing. use a name list studentsList. I have updated the code to use _boxListBox_ where it is required

Comment: OKAY IT WORKS! TYSM! You are a god!

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ expression to see if the item is exists or not.

```
if(ListBox.Items.Any(i=>i.Name == txtName.Text && i.LastName == txtLastName.Text && i.ClassRoom == txtClassRoom.Text)
{
   //Show MessageBox
}
```

Comment: Do you know if the ListBox has a DataSource set to a Student collection?

Comment: Uhm i dont know what that means.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the Equals operator in the Student class, then use the Contains method to check the list.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || !(obj is Student student))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return Name == student.Name && LastName == student.LastName && Classroom == student.Classroom && DateDay == student.DateDay;
}
```

Then to check the item:

```
if (!ListBox.Items.Contains(student))
{
    ListBox.Items.Add(student);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("You didnt fill out all the text boxes.", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```